# How to write this complicated UPDATE query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have the table Texts with the columns:

- wordcount (int)
- text (varchar 1024)

Currently wordcount is -1 in all the rows, but we would like to fill the column with these data:

- number of words in text, i.e. if text = "Hello Stackoverflow" => wordcount = 2
- if a word in the text is in a () or a [] it shouldn't count, i.e. "Hello to everyone on Stackoverflow" => wordcount = 5, but "Hello (to) everyone on Stackoverflow" => wordcount = 4 since (to) is in a ()

Anyone know how to write such an UPDATE query?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: The UPDATE query is easy: what will take a bit more work is writing the function that counts words.  Try googling for "SQL split words".

Comment: Have written this already:
UPDATE texts
SET wordcount = LEN(text) - LEN(REPLACE(text, ' ', '')) + 1

Problem is how to ignore () and []

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure that words a only separated by spaces (not by commas etc). You could do something like this:

X = string length using `LEN()`.

Y = length of the string after using `REPLACE()` to remove spaces from row.

Then X - Y is the number of spaces in the string and (X - Y) + 1 (first word) is number of words.

```
SELECT (LEN(text) - LEN(REPLACE(text, ' ', ''))) + 1 FROM Texts
```

And converted into update:

```
UPDATE TABLE TEXTS SET wordcount = (LEN(text) - LEN(REPLACE(text, ' ', ''))) + 1
```

Don't have MS SQL Server currently available so I cannot test this now.

Comment: This just like my own query (see above in the comments) - but it doesn't ignore the [] and () words

Answer (score 0):

Try this query :

```
UPDATE Texts SET wordcount = 
len( replace( replace( replace( replace(text ,' [' ,'' ) ,']' , '') ,' (' ,'' ),')' ,'' )) - 

len(replace( replace( replace( replace( replace(text ,' [' ,'' ) ,']' , '') ,' (' ,'' ),')' ,'' ),' ','')) +1
```

It's completely works on your test cases.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `SELECT` statement which counts the number of words, you can do the same to count the number of 'non-words' (surrounded by parenthesis).

```
SELECT (LEN(text) - LEN(REPLACE(text, ' ', ''))) + 1 - (
        LEN(text) - LEN(REPLACE(text, '(', ''))
        )
FROM TEXTS
```

Check out [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/26226) to see how the query works.

The update is pretty easy to make out of this:

```
UPDATE TEXTS
SET WORDCOUNT = (LEN(text) - LEN(REPLACE(text, ' ', ''))) + 1 - (
                 LEN(text) - LEN(REPLACE(text, '(', ''))
                )
```

This update will work only if your text is correctly formatted, all the open parenthesis which are open are closed (the number of `(` in your text is the same as the number of `)` in the text).

But if there are chances that there are more open/closed parenthesis around words than there shoud be, like in the case of a typo, you should use this:

```
SELECT (
    LEN(text) - LEN(REPLACE(text, ' ', ''))) 
    + 1 
    - (
    CASE
        WHEN LEN(text) - LEN(REPLACE(text, ')', '')) > LEN(text) - LEN(REPLACE(text, '(', ''))
          THEN LEN(text) - LEN(REPLACE(text, '(', ''))
        ELSE
          LEN(text) - LEN(REPLACE(text, ')', ''))
    END
   )
FROM TEXTS
```

You can find the [SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/26239).

In this case, the UPDATE statement will be like this:

```
UPDATE TEXTS
SET WORDCOUNT = (
        LEN(text) - LEN(REPLACE(text, ' ', ''))) 
        + 1 
        - (
        CASE
            WHEN LEN(text) - LEN(REPLACE(text, ')', '')) > LEN(text) - LEN(REPLACE(text, '(', ''))
              THEN LEN(text) - LEN(REPLACE(text, '(', ''))
            ELSE
              LEN(text) - LEN(REPLACE(text, ')', ''))
        END
       )
    )
```